# make file compiles but not run

Tags: gcc, makefile

```
# Macros
CC = gcc
COMP_FLAG = -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror -DNDEBUG
LIB_FLAG = -L. -lmtm -lex1
# Main target
tests: yad3_test realtor_test customer_test

# Targets make <file>

yad3_test: yad3_test.o yad3.o realtor.o customer.o
    $(CC) yad3_test.o yad3.o realtor.o customer.o $(LIB_FLAG) -o $@
yad3_test.o: tests/yad3_test.c yad3.h customer.h realtor.h apartment_service.h apartment.h tests/test_utilities.h mtm_ex2.h
    $(CC) -c $(COMP_FLAG) $(LIB_FLAG) tests/$*.c
yad3.o:  yad3.c yad3.h customer.h realtor.h apartment_service.h apartment.h mtm_ex2.h list.h map.h
    $(CC) -c $(COMP_FLAG) $(LIB_FLAG) $*.c
realtor.o: realtor.c realtor.h apartment_service.h apartment.h map.h
    $(CC) -c $(COMP_FLAG) $(LIB_FLAG) $*.c
customer.o: customer.c map.h customer.h
    $(CC) -c $(COMP_FLAG) $(LIB_FLAG) $*.c


realtor_test: realtor_test.o realtor.o
    $(CC) realtor_test.o realtor.o $(LIB_FLAG) -o $@
realtor_test.o: tests/realtor_test.c realtor.h apartment_service.h apartment.h tests/test_utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(COMP_FLAG) $(LIB_FLAG) tests/$*.c
#realtor.o: realtor.c realtor.h apartment_service.h apartment.h map.h
#   $(CC) -c $(COMP_FLAG) $(LIB_FLAG) $*.c


customer_test: customer_test.o customer.o
    $(CC) customer_test.o customer.o $(LIB_FLAG) -o $@
customer_test.o: tests/customer_test.c customer.h tests/test_utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(COMP_FLAG) $(LIB_FLAG) tests/$*.c
#customer.o: customer.c map.h customer.h
#   $(CC) -c $(COMP_FLAG) $(LIB_FLAG) $*.c



run: run_yad3_test run_realtor_test run_customer_test

run_clean: clean run

#run_my_set_test: my_set_test
#   ./my_set_test

run_yad3_test: yad3_test
    ./yad3_test

realtor_test_test: realtor_test
    ./realtor_test

run_customer_test: customer_test
    ./customer_test

# Target remove all <*_test> and <*.o> files
clean: clean_o clean_test

clean_test:
    rm -f *_test
clean_o:
    rm -f *.o
```

Is there any logical reason that the compiling is working fine, but it doesn't run the final created tests properly ???

It seemed to be written correctly adn there is not any reason. it shouldn't work. Help anybody?

Comment: Neither the main target, nor it's dependencies depend on `run`. Try with `make run` or adding `run` as  a `tests` dependency

Comment: make run worked. But I want that it do it withhout writing make run. 
I've added as a dependency, but  it wrote "no rule to make run_realtor_test". ???

Comment: Because there is no such a rule, the one you have is named realtor_test_test

Answer (score 1):

By default `make` run the first target of the file, so you can just move the `run` rule at the top and `make` will `make run`.

Also since `GNU Make 3.81` a `.DEFAULT_GOAL` permit to override this behavior, so, if you want, keep the actual order, add:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL = run
```